# How to show SQL results in separate lines using PHP?

Tags: php, sql

So, I have this little search engine Im working on, where I can look for error messages, and as a result, I get links to known solutions, and other information
It's something I use for my work as tech support engineer
I spend most of my days just googling things and looking into different internal locations for solutions to known issues
I wanted to build a one stop shop where I can enter an error code, and I get all related information to it

For this I created a database, which has 4 columns:
Error Name: the error code I'm looking for
KBs: knowledge base articles related to that error
Other Links: links to non-company sites with solutions to the same error
Cases: internal case numbers

So, if I search for Error1, I get that information, and it's fine if I just have one link for each one of them, but usually, I have multiple sources for any named error

So, on the database, for example I have the column Cases, populated with several case numbers (separated by a comma)
And the php I have right now, is showing me the results as:

```
123,234,345,456,567
```

And I would like to display that as:

```
123
234
345
456
567
```

The code I have for this is:

```
$sql = "SELECT errorname, kbs, otherinfo, cases FROM issues WHERE id = $id";

<?php echo $row['cases']; ?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Learn how to normalize your data - https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/normalization-1nf-2nf-3nf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most important skills in programming is *breaking the problem down*.

All the details about the database, and why you're building it, are completely irrelevant to the current problem you're trying to solve, which can be written as:

> I have a list of items in a comma-separated string. I want to display each item on a separate line.

What *is* relevant is where you're viewing the output; I'm going to guess you're outputting HTML, so all you really need to know is that [a line break in HTML is spelled `<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

So we can re-word the problem more specifically:

> I have a string separated by `,`. I want it to be separated by `<br>` instead.

Thinking about other ways of rewording this, you might easily come up with:

> I want to replace every `,` in my string with `<br>`

Then you look in the PHP manual, and you find [a function called `str_replace`](https://php.net/str_replace) whose summary reads:

> Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

I'll leave the actual PHP code to you; if you can't figure out from there, you should probably give up and become a farmer or something

---

There are of course other variations of the problem, such as:

> For each item, I want to output an item in a bulleted list

Which leads you to:

- the concisely named [HTML `<ul>` and `<li>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) ("unordered list" and "list item", respectively) ...
- ... the helpfully named [`foreach` loop](https://php.net/foreach) ...
- ... and the alarmingly named [`explode` function](https://php.net/explode) which separates a string into items

Comment: Is this more of a comment than an answer? I do agree with the comment.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I started writing it as a comment, but then realized that this is basically all there is to say. The answer to the actual question is in here, I just took the "teach a man to fish" approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render it for **HTML** you've to use

```
<?php echo $row['cases'] . '<br>'; ?>
```

If you want to have a line break in the HTML-source code too you can write

```
<?php echo $row['cases'] . "<br>\n"; ?>
```

If you want to render it for **Text files** you've to use this:

```
<?php echo $row['cases'] . "\n"; ?>
```

For other file formats it might have to be noted differently but you've to define which file-format you use then.